# How to enable a button in different cases in swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I want to disable, and enable a button in different cases:

If the user comes to my share viewController the button will be disabled:

```
func handleShareAndAbortButton() {
    shareButton.isEnabled = false
    abortButton.isEnabled = false

    let attributedShareButtonText = NSAttributedString(string: shareButton.currentTitle!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2) ])
    let attributedabortButtonText = NSAttributedString(string: abortButton.currentTitle!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2) ])
    shareButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedShareButtonText, for: .normal)
    abortButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedabortButtonText, for: .normal)
}
```

The `handleShareAndAbortButton` will be called in `viewDidLoad`

If something changed (picture or text) I want to enable the button:

```
func imageDidChange() {
    selectedText = postTextView.text!

    let isText = selectedText
    let isImage = selectedImage != nil

    if isImage || isText != "Schreibe etwas..." && isText != nil {
    shareButton.isEnabled = true
    abortButton.isEnabled = true

    let attributedShareButtonText = NSAttributedString(string: shareButton.currentTitle!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0) ])
    let attributedabortButtonText = NSAttributedString(string: abortButton.currentTitle!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0) ])
    shareButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedShareButtonText, for: .normal)
    abortButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedabortButtonText, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

I call the `imageDidChange` in `viewWillAppear`

Here I delete the placeholder after begin editing:

```
   extension ShareViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if postTextView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            postTextView.text = nil
            postTextView.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if postTextView.text.isEmpty {
            postTextView.text = "Schreibe etwas..."
            postTextView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }
}
```

When the user now enter some text, the placeholder "Schreibe etwas..." will be gone and the text will be also != nil. But its not working.

**Update**

I found out the problem. When I delete the `isText != "Schreibe etwas..."`
it works. But I need this. How can I compare to a String? If I don't have this code, the user is able to upload always with placeholder text.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: And in viewDidAppear it works?

Comment: its in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: with the picture it works but if I want only to post text it doesn't work

Comment: Where you call imageDidChange? It should also be called in textViewDidEndEditing

Comment: I call the `imageDidChange` in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: but after you changed the text in postTextView viewWillAppear will not get called. So you never set the button to enabled true

Comment: works for me perfect thank you! I need to call ìmageDidChange` also in `textViewDidEndEditing` Make a answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Gern geschehen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call `imageDidChange` after you changed the text.

Use:

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
     if postTextView.text.isEmpty {
         postTextView.text = "Schreibe etwas..."
         postTextView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
     }

     imageDidChange()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you’re using `UITextField`. You probably want to have just placeholder `"Schreibe etwas..."`. So, in `viewDidLoad` or in Storyboard set placeholder of your TextField to "Schreibe etwas...". Then you don’t need TextField’s delegate methods for setting text and color of text in delegate methods.

Well, you need it, but not for this. You **have to call** `imageDidChange` in `textFieldDidEndEditing`

Now change declaring `isText`. You just passed reference for `selectedText`. Don’t do this, just check if there is text

```
let isText = !selectedText.isEmpty // don’t forget to !
```

also rewrite your conditions

```
if isImage || isText
```

... you don’t need to check if `isText` isn’t`nil`