# How to compare two strings in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, compare

I have the following problem:

I want to compare if one string contains `"Schreibe etwas..."`

I solved it with the following code:

```
selectedText = postTextView.text!
let isText = selectedText

if isText != "Schreibe etwas..." {
    shareButton.isEnabled = true
    abortButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

But its not working.
How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is `isText` ? BTW, this is right way to compare string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
if !isText.contains("Schreibe etwas...") {
    shareButton.isEnabled = true
    abortButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: I think the "..." is not part of his text.

Comment: but the op set it look to the comparison

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I want to check if it Doesn't contains "Schreibe etwas..."

Comment: simply put **!** see edit .........

Comment: Look at this question for my full question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850023/how-to-enable-a-button-in-different-cases-in-swift] 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
let myString =  isText.absoluteString
if myString.range(of:"Schreibe etwas") != nil { 

//do some thing

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to compare two String

```
  var a : String = "Schreibe etwas..."
  var b  : String = "Schreibe etwas..."

  if(a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b) == .orderedSame){
      print("string is Same")
  }
```